# Why does the value not change in database after UPDATE statement?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

The following subroutine should update the text in the database to new user input, however, when I check the database nothing has changed?

```cs
private void UpdatePassword(string Username, string NewPassword)
{
    string SQLStatement =
        "UPDATE [Login Details] SET [PASSWORD] = @password WHERE [USERNAME] = @username";

    OleDbConnection connString = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = TrigonometryToolDatabase.accdb");
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SQLStatement, connString);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Username);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", NewPassword);

    connString.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connString.Close();
}
```

Comment: Check the result of `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` which returns the number of results affected by the SQL statement. re: `int rows - cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` If zero rows, then there was no matching user name. FYI, you should also be using `using` statements which will correctly dispose of the connection.

Comment: Completely tangential to your problem, but do not store passwords in plain-text in your database. If you are building a system that ever had a chance to be used in real life, or if you just want to have more tools to use, start researching encryption and [salted hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) to store encrypted passwords.

Answer (score 3):

Parameters in MS Access / OleDB is **positional** - they are **NOT** matched on name (like in ADO.NET / SQL Server) - but on their position in the query string.

You have

```
string SQLStatement =
    "UPDATE [Login Details] SET [PASSWORD] = @password WHERE [USERNAME] = @username";
```

so the **first** parameter you pass in will need to be the **password**, the username comes second.

However, in your code, you're doing it just the other way around:

```
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Username);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", NewPassword);
```

So flip these two lines, and you should be good:

```
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", NewPassword);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Username);
```